# ArcGIS Multiband Raster

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, zonal-statistics

I know this has been asked and answered here but since I don't have enough rep to ask a clarifying question to the person who answered it I am having to post a completely different question.

I am trying to perform zonal stats on a geotiff with 6 bands (RGB and three thermal and NIR bands). Like the post below it only calculates the stats on the first band.

[How does ArcGIS calculate zonal statistics with multi-band rasters?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/164064/how-does-arcgis-calculate-zonal-statistics-with-multi-band-rasters?answertab=oldest#tab-top)

In the screen shot in the above post, it appears that you can select a specific band when you select the "Input value raster", however mine doesn't look like this. I simply get the Raster Datasets rather than the Raster Bands.

So my question is, how do I get the individual bands so I can calculate zonal stats on each band in this way? Is it that I have to somehow export single bands as new rasters - if so how do you go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to export to single bands, there are a couple of ways of adding bands to the tool directly from the original multiband dataset:

- double click on the raster dataset in the file dialog.
- click on the + symbol next to the raster name in the Catalog window in ArcMap (or ArcCatalog). If you can't see any + symbols in the Catalog window  tree, click the Toggle Contents Panel button in the Catalog window toolbar.

If you want to be able to add the bands using the dropdown in the tool, you have to add the band individually to the ArcMap TOC, as per above, either using the Add Data button, or Catalog.

Comment: Thanks, I think the issue I was having was the 'double click' part. I was just selecting the geotif and not realising that when you add the file you can double click on the actual file to select the bands.

Answer (score 2):

You can add individual raster bands to ArcGIS and process them individually.  You can also break a raster into its individual bands.  This questions has instructions for both: [Extracting one band from three band raster in ArcMap?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/85895/how-to-extract-one-band-from-a-three-band-raster-in-arcmap)