# How do I select from a multiband raster?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, multi-band

I have a multiband raster (RGB) and I'd like to select out the watercourses to create a new raster.

[image]

Examining the data it seems I can do so by selecting blue > 100, Red <100, Green <100. Is there a way to create a new raster based on an sql query, where all pixels that meet the criteria are differentiated from those that don't?

I have the spatial analyst extension. I saw the [Extract By Attributes](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/extract-by-attributes.htm) tool, but this just allows me to select by `Value`.

[image]

Ideally my end product would be a binary raster that differentiates between those pixels that meet the given criteria and those that do not.

Comment: I can remember someone telling me this was 'easy' in photoshop (and GIMP too I suppose), it might be worth your while looking around in those forums; beware that raster editors destroy georeference in GeoTIFFs - they don't recognize Geo Tags but instead of just maintaining the values they don't understand (garbage-in garbage-out) they tend to not write them... The good news is that World files aren't affected so you can use TFW files to *bank* your georeference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add each band to ArcMap [individually](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/180035/2856).
Use [`Con`](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/con-.htm) to evaluate your expression in the raster calculator:

```
Con(("Blue" > 100) & ("Red" < 100) & ("Green" < 100), 1)
```

Which will output a raster of 1 and NoData.  If you want 1 and 0 output, just use:

```
(("Blue" > 100) & ("Red" < 100) & ("Green" < 100))
```

Answer (score 1):

I have had no success trying to do what you are doing. I use image classification now and have reasonable success when features I am looking to pull are very different than their surroundings; it appears that this is your case:

http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/spatial-analyst/image-classification/image-classification-using-spatial-analyst.htm